# How to pass String data from API POST request to another ViewController

Tags: swift, api, post, request, viewcontroller

I am absolutely beginner in Swift and programming at all.

I don't know how to pass a response from my function that calls POST request to the text label on the second view controller. I think that it may be something wrong with the main thread but I don't know how to solve it.  I really try to search for the solution but nothing works for me.

Here is my function:

```
 func getBookTitle() -> String {
        
        var bookTitle = ""
            
        
        if let bookNameURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            
            do {
                let htmlString = try String(contentsOf: bookNameURL, encoding: .utf8)
                let htmlContent = htmlString
                
                do {
                    let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent)
                    
                    do {
                        let bookNumber = try doc.select("a.dlink").attr("onclick")
                        let bookNumberTrim = bookNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).components(separatedBy: ",")
                        
                        do {
                            
                            let bookid = bookNumberTrim[0]
                            let passageid = bookNumberTrim[1]
                            
                            
                            print(bookid)
                            print(passageid)
                            
                            
                            
                            //Get Book Title
                            
                            let url:URL = URL(string: "\(urlString)/getname")!
                            let session = URLSession.shared
                            
                            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
                            request.httpMethod = "POST"
                            request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
                            
                            let paramString = "bookid=\(bookid)&passageid=\(passageid)"
                            
                            request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
                            
                            

                            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                                
                                
                                guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                                    print("error")
                                    return
                                }
                                
                                let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))
                                
                                
                                do {
                                    
                                    let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(dataString ?? "")
                                    
                                    do {
                                        
                                        let bTitle = try doc.select("div").first()
                                        bookTitle = try bTitle!.text()
                                        
                                        print(bookTitle)
                                        
                                    }
                                } catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                                
                            }
                            task.resume()
                            
                            
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                        
                    }
                }
                
            } catch let error {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
            
            
        } else {
            print("Something wrong")
        }
        
        return bookTitle
        
    }
```

This is how I am trying to pass data to another VC:

```
@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToInfo", sender: sender)
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    
    if segue.identifier == "goToInfo" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! BookInfoVC
        
        destinationVC.bookName = networkService.getBookTitle()

    }
    
}
```

And second VC:

```
class BookInfoVC: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bookTitle: UILabel!
    
    var bookName: String!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        bookTitle.text = bookName
        
    }
    
}
```

The response that comes from the function is one String line.

Many thanks!

---

**UPD:**
I've tried to implement completion handler in my function and now it looks like this:

```
func getBookTitle(completion: @escaping (String) -> ()) {
        
        if let bookNameURL = URL(string: urlString) {
            
            do {
                let htmlString = try String(contentsOf: bookNameURL, encoding: .utf8)
                let htmlContent = htmlString
                
                do {
                    let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlContent)
                    
                    
                    do {
                        let bookNumber = try doc.select("a.dlink").attr("onclick")
                        let bookNumberTrim = bookNumber.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).components(separatedBy: ",")
                        
                        
                        do {
                            let bookid = bookNumberTrim[0]
                            let passageid = bookNumberTrim[1]
                        
                            
                            
                            //MARK: - Fetch book title
                            
                            let params = BookTitle(bookid: bookid, passageid: passageid)
                            
                            
                            AF.request("\(self.urlString)/getname", method: .post, parameters: params).validate(contentType: ["application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]).response { (response) in
                                
                                
                                
                                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                                    
                                    
                                    do {
                                        let html: String = utf8Text
                                        let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)

                                        do {

                                            let parseTitle = try doc.select("div").first()
                                            let bookTitle = try parseTitle!.text()
                                            completion(bookTitle)

                                        } catch {
                                            print(error)
                                        }
                                        
                                        
                                    } catch {
                                        print(error)
                                    }
  
                                }
                            
                            }
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                    
                }
                
            } catch let error {
                print("Error \(error)")
            }
                        
            
        } else {
            print("Something wrong")
        }
        
    }
```

And I call it this:

```
@IBAction func infoButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToInfo", sender: self)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    

    if segue.identifier == "goToInfo" {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! BookInfoVC
        
        
        networkService.getBookTitle { bookTitle in
            destinationVC.bookName = bookTitle
            print(bookTitle)

        }

    }
```

I've tried to paste DispatchQueue.main.async everywhere, but it still doesn't update the text label on the second VC. But in the main view controller, it's working fine.

Comment: `func getBookTitle()` calls an asynchronous function `session.dataTask` - see [Returning data from async call in Swift function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function)

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire is a great package for performing API calls and handles a lot of the annoying stuff for you. It's also great for learning by reading the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. You are making an async request. The function will return before the results are available. You need to rewrite your function to take a completion handler. You would then invoke the completion handler when the result is available. This is widely discussed on this board.

### Edit:

Your updated `getBookTitle(completion:)` function looks good, but now you have a sequencing problem.

Your `prepare(for segue:)` method in your first view controller uses your `networkService.getBookTitle(completion:)` function, and in the completion handler it sets `destinationVC.bookName`.

However, remember that `networkService.getBookTitle(completion:)` runs asynchronously. It returns immediately, waits for the network result, and **then** invokes the completion handler.

Your destination view controller, (of type `BookInfoVC`) tries to install `bookName` into its UI in its `viewDidLoad` method. `viewDidLoad()` gets called immediately after the first view controller's `prepare(for segue:)` fires. At the time viewDidLoad is called, `bookName` is very likely still nil.

You need to add a didSet method on your `BookInfoVC`'s `bookName` property so it responds to a change to the book name. That might look like this:

```
var bookName: String! {
   didSet: {
     bookTitle.text = bookName
   }
}
```

If you do that, when getBookTitle()'s completion handler fires, it will change `destinationVC.bookName`. That will cause the `BookInfoVC`'s `bookName` `didSet` code to fire, installing the updated `bookName` into the UI.

Comment: Hello! Can you review my code again, please? I updated it above.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. Resist the urge to "paste DispatchQueue.main.async everywhere". Instead, take the time to understand what's going on. Add print statements in each step of your code, run it, and look carefully at the order in which the print statements are executed. With async code and completion handlers things can happen in an order that you might not expect.